# Need help on the Optaplanner, Quarkus with sudoku

Tags: optaplanner, sudoku, quarkus

Did anyone used latest Optaplanner (using Quarkus + Optaplanner) to solve a Sudoku problem ?

Currently I am working on a constraing programming to solve the Sudoku problem. I have followed the recent video uploaded by Geoffrey (https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/video.html ) and done almost the entire coding and defined Constraint, still, before I move ahead I need to validate my understanding on this.

Comment: What are you stuck on in particular?

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, I am actually stuck in creating the "DemoDataGeneator" part. As i am new to stackoverflow, is there a way i can paste / attach my code ?

Comment: I am able to solve the Sudoku Problem with latest library (7.36.0.Final) through a Spring boot application